# Clarifications on hyperbolic identity

Tags: trigonometry

On one of my workings in a tutorial sheet, 
It is stated that

$$\left.\text{ae}^{\left(\frac{n\ \pi \
   x}{H}\right)}+\text{be}^{-\left(\frac{\text{n$\pi
   $x}}{H}\right)}\text{=aCosh(}\frac{\text{n$\pi $x}}{H}\text{)+bSinh(}\frac{\text{-n$\pi
   $x}}{H}\right)$$

But in working through I found that it should be

$$\left.\text{ae}^{\left(\frac{n\ \pi \
   x}{H}\right)}+\text{be}^{-\left(\frac{\text{n$\pi
   $x}}{H}\right)}\text{=aCosh(}\frac{\text{n$\pi $x}}{H}\text{)+aSinh(}\frac{\text{n$\pi
   $x}}{H}\text{)+bCosh(}\frac{-\text{n$\pi $x}}{H}\text{)-bSinh(}\frac{-\text{n$\pi
   $x}}{H}\right)$$

I would appreciate some clarification.

Edit:Typo has been rectified

Comment: You probably mean $\text{ae}^{\left(\frac{n\ \pi \
   x}{H}\right)}+\text{be}^{\left(\frac{-\text{n$\pi
   $x}}{H}\right)}$.

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the typo. Will have it corrected again.

Comment: Is there a reason why you write $\displaystyle \left.\text{ae}^{\left(\frac{n\ \pi \
   x}{H}\right)}+\text{be}^{-\left(\frac{\text{n$\pi
   $x}}{H}\right)}\text{=aCosh(}\frac{\text{n$\pi $x}}{H}\text{)+bSinh(}\frac{\text{-n$\pi
   $x}}{H}\right)$ instead of $\displaystyle ae^{n\pi x/H} + be^{-n\pi x/H}= a \cosh\left(\frac{n\pi x}H\right) + b\sinh\left(\frac{-n\pi x}H\right)$?  The first form takes a lot more effort to write and results in non-standard and awkward forms, including lack of spacing between $a$ and $\cosh$ and a mismatch in sizes of parentheses. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy 
That's true but I usually leave Mathematica's TeXForm to transmute the string of elements into LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect $$ae^{(\frac{n\pi x}{H})} + be^{(\frac{-n\pi x}{H})} = (a+b)\cosh\left(\frac{n\pi x}{H}\right) + (a-b)\sinh\left(\frac{n\pi x}{H}\right)  $$ which is close to what you have if you track the signs and use the even and odd properties of cosh and sinh.

You can quickly see that the first equation is wrong by substituting $x=0$.

Comment: Yes this was what I got after reworking. The 'negative' signs in the cosh and sinh in the op were a mix of typo and careless mistake.
Indeed, I had Mathematica confirmed this identity.